# How is a symbol (ex. :label) handled as part of a parameter hash

Tags: ruby

I was looking at example code from the O'Reilly book on Ruby on Rails and ran across this:

```
 def label_for(method, options={})
    extra = ""
    if options[:required]
      extra = " <span class='required_mark'>*</span>"
    end
    label(:label || method) + extra + "<br />"
  end
```

I understand that `options` is a hash, but how is it able to call `label` with just `:label` -- shouldn't it need to say `options[:label]` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I believe so, otherwise the `:label` symbol will always be passed as a `method` name to `label` helper.

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be `options[:label]` unless the author really had something else in mind. Because `:label || method` is always going return `:label` which is then passed to the label method.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

```
label(options[:label] || method) + extra + "<br />"
```

Comment: haha, all saying the same here... beaten to the post on a typo :-)
Kudos to @khelll and @Chirantan